# How to Create Popup Window in baseadapter class in android (closed)

Tags: android, listview, popup, baseadapter

In my baseadapter class there is a textview on which when click action apply a popup window is appear and popup window cotains a list of numbers fom 1-10.
 When i select any number from the list then the result affects only last row of the Mainlist (for which adapter is created).

**My Problem is :** The popup window is open at the place where the text view is shown, but i want to open it in the whole screen of perticular weidth and height.

Any one here who can resolve this problem?
thanks in advance...
Here is Code of Adapter class

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{ 
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_item_row, null);

    count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.count);
    count.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                PopupWindow popUp = popupWindowshow(v);
                popUp.showAsDropDown(v, 0, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    return v;
}

private PopupWindow popupWindowshow(View v) {

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(activity);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item_arrays));
    final ListView countList = new ListView(activity);

    countList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // set on item selected
    countList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String data = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(activity, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            count.setText(data);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            popupWindow.dismiss();

        }
    });

    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    popupWindow.setWidth(250);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.color.white));
    popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // set the listview as popup content
    popupWindow.setContentView(countList);
    return popupWindow;
}
```

Comment: did you face any problem....

Comment: yes that's why i am asking this question.

Comment: then define your problem.. or what is the error..??

Comment: read the question i was defined there also in steps.

Comment: the first problem is because you are using `popupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);` where the v is the textview you clicked, thats why the pop up will be shown at the textview

Comment: yes i know that the popwill be showing in the center of text view but what i have to do for show it in the MailList view center. because the popup is in adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by taking custom Dialog box at the place of Popup window in base adapter because adapter item width and height is the parent height for the Popup window so thats why window is not full screen.
thank you for giving time.